# Avoiding nil Slider Values?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Anybody have suggestions on how to avoid getting errors due to sliders being nil when switching between view controllers?  My app has a main screen that controls audio playing and buttons to five other view controllers.  One that allows audio file selection, and four that have parameters to adjust distortion, filter, reverb, and delay parameters.  I am using unwind segues to get back to the main screen from these separate screens.  The issue is that the optionals are nil when I load the project since they are on a separate view controller.  I want to be able to access these parameters, adjust them in real time and go back to the menu with the parameters maintaining their new values.  Another aspect of this issue is that I will load my audio file in the "select audio file" controller that I have, but when I switch back to the main view controller, the loaded song reverts back to nil in the audio player after the unwind.  Any suggestions on how to organize the view controllers to allow this functionality would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you have default values you want to use when these values are nil, you can use the nil coalescing operator "??"

```
someParameter = slider?.value ?? someParameter
```

Would probably be okay I guess? I'd be very careful tying your sound to the view controller life cycle. Probably your slider should talk to a central audio data store (sometimes I'll call it the conductor or engine) and have that be the only thing that truly changes audio parameter values, and have it do so with care.

Comment: I'll play around with the coalescing operator and see if it helps!

I have a single ViewController.swift file that controls everything.  All the other view controllers are connected to this file via the class section of the identity inspector.  Is this what you mean by using a single conductor?

Comment: However, I think the issue is that when I segue to a new view controller, the AKSliders themselves are nil.  For example, if I comment out all the code related to distortion, filter, reverb, and delay and just add the volume slider onto the main view controller, I can load the project with no issues.  Then, when I click away from the main screen, this volume slider is interpreted as nil and the app crashes.